# HTML - MySQL Table delete entry

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a problem. I want a Table on my page, which shows things from a MySQL DB. This works just fine:

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=********', '********', '********');

$sql = "SELECT subject, givenOn, toDate, teacher, what FROM homework";

echo "<table>";

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row){

//              echo "Fach:" .  $row['subject'] . " - Lehrer:" . $row['teacher'] . " - Was: " . $row['what'] .  $

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>", $row['subject'], "</td>";
                echo "<td>", $row['teacher'], "</td>";
                echo "<td>", $row['what'], "</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
        }

echo "</table>";
?>
```

But I want another column behind the "what" - one which contains a Link to remove the Line. I dont know how its possible to say the Links what he has to delete. My idea was a PhP Page which has arguments like:

```
delete.php?subject=math&teacher=smith&what=p13
```

But this is very unsecure, isnt it?

Have u any Ideas how I can solve this problem?

dunklesToast

Comment: `"But this is very unsecure, isnt it?"` - What makes you think that?  In order to delete the record, *some* request has to be sent to the server.  Why would such a request not be secure?  `"how I can solve this problem?"` - You already proposed creating a `delete.php` page which deletes the record.  Did you *try* doing that?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Instead of creating a link in your DB, create a anchor with an onClick function for each row, specifying the information.

Comment: Look into CSRF prevention. Also you may probably want to look into XSS prevention.

Comment: @David I think its unsecure, because when anybody finds out the args, he can delete what he want. That a DELETE Request needs to be send to the DB is clearly.

Comment: @dunklesToast: That's why your `delete.php` page would *validate* that the user making the request is *authorized* to perform that action.  If the user is not authorized, return an error indicating as such.  The actual act of deleting a record doesn't take place in a URL, it takes place in your code.  Make your code secure.

Comment: @David verifying the user does nothing to prevent CSRF attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is.

1, you need to control who can delete an item, which is a rbac system.

2, delete should use POST rather than GET.

3,use PDOStatement::bindParam to prevent sql injection.